# In Django, how can I use a request to determine its URLconf viewname?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I can get the view function from `request.path`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
view_func, _args, _kwargs = resolve(request.path)
```

However, I need something more. I need to take a list of view names, like `['edit_foo', 'delete_foo']`, and find out if the current URL is for one of those.

I've come up with a couple ideas using some internals from `django.core.urlresolvers`, but I want something that will be efficient and somewhat correct (ie, not hacky, ideally documented).

Comment: Why can't you have a list of the views instead?

Comment: @Ignacio - do you mean, a list of actual callable view functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing that long question, I figured it out :/ (posting for whoever else runs into this, by chance). It's quite simple:

```
>>> resolve(request.path).url_name
'edit_foo'
```

I must have been mistaken about the `resolve` function's usefulness, which is vast.

Comment: Can you link in where you found that in the docs? **Edit:** Nevermind, here it is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#s-resolve **AND** this is only applicable to Django 1.3+. Previous versions do not have this available.

Comment: @chrisdpratt - ah, good point. I use trunk for personal projects, worth noting.